# Join YouTube chrome-cast session from android sender app

Tags: android, chromecast

Hi I have a sender app that checks what is running on the chrome-cast by using the metadata returned on joinApplication() since just getApplicationMetadata() doesn't work at the moment. However joinApplication() doesn't work for receiver apps that use the old SDK (Such as YouTube).

I have been googling for information about how to join these sessions for some time, but cannot find anything helpful so I ask you good people of stack overflow. (I hope the answer includes where to get the old sdk, if it is required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are not able to join a YT session with the official SDK. Even if you find the old SDK, you won't be able to write an app with it since old whitelisting approach doesn't work any more.